# Error MT2002: Failed to resolve assembly: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.iOS

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios14

I have updated my xamarin.ios project to **IOS14** SDK and i am getting the following build error

`Error MT2002: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' (MT2002)`

I understand that the Azure Mobile Services Library is deprecated, however is there a way that i can build my project without migrating to Azure Mobile Apps?

#September 2021 Update

With `Xamarin.iOS 14.20.0.24` i continue to have the error

Comment: You could uninstall the library and install the new library **Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server**  from Nuget . And for more details you could check https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server .

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang. As i have stated in my question, i am looking for a solution without migrating to Azure Mobile Apps. Is there any?